# How to validate time format input?

Tags: python, string

So basically, i needed to write a program that takes the time of how fast you run a kilometer, and turn it into how long it takes to run a marathon. I got that done, but the problem is that it is supposed to handle if someone inputs the time incorrectly (ex 888 or 5:2555 instead of 8:30)

```
print "Marathon Time Calculator"
str_pace = raw_input("At what pace do you run a km? (e.g. 5:30): ")

if str_pace.isalpha():
print 'invalid time'

split_pace = str_pace.split(":")

minutes = int(split_pace[0])
seconds = int(split_pace[1])

str_pace = minutes * 60 + seconds
totalTime = str_pace * 42

hours = totalTime // 3600
timeLeft = totalTime % 3600

minutes = timeLeft // 60
seconds = timeLeft % 60

if len(split_pace[1]) >= 3:
  print "Too many digits"
else:
  print "You should complete a marathon in " + str(hours) + ":" + str(minutes) + ":" + str(seconds)
```

Comment: What format are you looking for specifically? 17:30 or 5:30pm ?

Comment: Once you know that you can use some simple regex to validate the input and handle the exceptions accordingly

Comment: Based on his question, probably the former: `At what pace do you run a km? (e.g. 5:30)`   5:30pm doesn't make any sense as a running pace

Comment: Arr apologies yes, its a time stop watch type time stamp not an actual time. Give me a mo ill put something together quick using your code as an example

Comment: Also another thing is that the time should be printed in proper format (right now it might print 1:45:2 instead of 1:45:02)

Comment: That is a different question, but modify your post to include both questions

Comment: your post title is a little misleading to the question to, may i suggest you title it something like "How to validate time format input"

Comment: Never mind on the second part there, already figured it out

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in python3

```
import re
import sys

print("Marathon Time Calculator")
str_pace = input("At what pace do you run a km? (e.g. 5:30): ")

# this is looking for a decimal value of 1 number, then a colon then another decimal value of 1 - 2 numbers
pattern = '\d{1}\:\d{1,2}' 

# this is doing the actual check against the pattern for us
match = re.match(pattern, str_pace)

# we now check if there is a match to our pattern
if not match:
    print('Invalid Time Input Try Again')
    sys.exit
else:
    # yes we are entering the value correctly continue the code
    split_pace = str_pace.split(":")

    minutes = int(split_pace[0])
    seconds = int(split_pace[1])

    str_pace = minutes * 60 + seconds
    totalTime = str_pace * 42

    hours = totalTime // 3600
    timeLeft = totalTime % 3600

    minutes = timeLeft // 60
    seconds = timeLeft % 60

    print("You should complete a marathon in {}:{}:{}".format(hours, minutes, seconds))
```

Comment: I havent checked any of the maths, I have simply answered your question on input validation

Answer (score 0):

I would create a separated function to do the validation

```
import sys

def valid(str_pace):
   #inappropriate digits
   for x in str_pace:
      if (not x.isdigit()) and (not x == ':'): return False
   split_pace = str_pace.split(":")

   #incorrect format
   if len(split_pace) != 2: return False 
   if len(split_pace[0]) == 0: return False 
   if len(split_pace[1]) != 1 and len(split_pace[1]) != 2: return False 

   #wrong amount of seconds
   seconds = int(split_pace[1])
   if seconds >= 60: return False 

   return True


print ("Marathon Time Calculator")
str_pace = input("At what pace do you run a km? (mm:ss): ")

if not valid(str_pace):
   print ("Invalid time format")
   sys.exit
else:
   split_pace = str_pace.split(":")

   minutes = int(split_pace[0])
   seconds = int(split_pace[1])

   str_pace = minutes * 60 + seconds
   totalTime = str_pace * 42

   hours = totalTime // 3600
   timeLeft = totalTime % 3600

   minutes = timeLeft // 60
   seconds = timeLeft % 60
   print (f"You should complete a marathon in {hours}:{minutes}:{seconds}")
```

The function validates if there are just **numbers and ':'**, and if the minutes and seconds were **correctly inserted**.

If you want to know which error occurred, you can print it in the function or return a code value for each error (e.g: 1 for wrong characters, 2 for wrong format and so on)